# Flex 4: Cannot use gif animation in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am very new to Flex, and now learning how to use gif animation for a work project. The example below is a very simple flash player (for testing purposes). All I need to do is to show the spinner.gif running, when the player is playing. Without the spinner, player is working fine, but nothing appears on the screen when I add "show_spinner" function and line

`<local:AnimatedGIFImage id="spinner" source="spinner.gif" visible="false" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"/>`.

The brouser window is simply blank. I searched on the web, but did not find the answer yet. I think that I don't understand fully the way flash player displays components.. Would be very gratefull for any advice.

**Spinner.mxml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                xmlns:local="*"
                xmlns:s="spark.components.*" layout="vertical" verticalAlign="top"
                backgroundColor="white"
                viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html"
                creationComplete="initApp()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.VideoEvent;

        private function videoDisplay_ready():void {
            videoDisplay.visible = true;
            controlBar.visible = true;
        }

        private function show_spinner(evt:mx.events.VideoEvent):void {
            if (evt.state == "playing") {
                spinner.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                spinner.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        private function initApp(){
            videoDisplay.addChild(spinner);
        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <s:Group>
        <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" visible="false" width="{200}" height="{200}"
                         ready="videoDisplay_ready()"
                         source="http://www.derekentringer.com/flv/purple_plasma.flv"
                         stateChange="show_spinner(event)">
        </mx:VideoDisplay>

        <mx:ControlBar id="controlBar" visible="false">
            <mx:Button id="play" name="play" label="Play" click="videoDisplay.play()"></mx:Button>
            <mx:Button id="pause" name="pause" label="Pause" click="videoDisplay.pause()"></mx:Button>
        </mx:ControlBar>

        <local:AnimatedGIFImage id="spinner" source="spinner.gif" visible="false" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"/>

    </s:Group>
</mx:Application>
```

**AnimatedGIFImage.as** file (from http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/animated-gifs-in-flex/):

```
package
{
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import mx.controls.Image;
import mx.core.UIComponent;

import org.bytearray.gif.player.GIFPlayer;

public class AnimatedGIFImage extends Image
{
    private var _gifImage  : UIComponent;

    public function AnimatedGIFImage()
    {
        super();
        this._gifImage  = new UIComponent();
    }

    override public function set source(value : Object) : void
    {
        if (!value is String)
        {
            throw new ArgumentError("Source must be of type String");
        }

        super.source = value;
    }

    override protected function createChildren() : void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        var player : GIFPlayer = new GIFPlayer();
        player.load(new URLRequest(this.source as String));
        this._gifImage.addChild(player);
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void
    {
        this.addChild(this._gifImage);
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you see the spinner if you just set `visible="true"` in the MXML markup for it, without calling `show_spinner`?

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried this, and the answer is "no", the screen is blank (no player, and no spinner).

Comment: Where is spinner.gif in your project?

Comment: spinner.gif is in src folder, together with the Spinner.mxml and AnimatedGIFImage.as files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might try:

- Right click your project and click "Properties"
- Click "Flex Compiler"
- Make sure "Copy non-embedded files to output folder" is checked

This will make it so that the image will be in copied in to your output folder (usually bin-debug in your project). After you compile, you can actually open that folder and see if the file made it in. If it's not in there, try manually copying the file in there and see if it works. Or you could try a normal image just to see if it's working at all in that location.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help. The gif file is indeed in the output folder.

Comment: I copied your code and tried it locally and the gif showed up fine. I hit a stack trace when using Flex SDK 4.6. You can change your s:Group to a mx:Canvas to fix that. Using Flex SDK 4.13, the video part didn't show up, but the gif still did with no stack traces. The only thing I don't have is your spinner.gif. I used the diego.gif that came with the GIFPlayer. I included the GIFPlayer code by just copying the org folder in to my project src folder.

Comment: That's good news, thank you, will try that too :) I am using Flex SDK 4.6, will also try that diego.gif file.

Comment: I figured that the gif file is indeed working when I use firefox browser, but not in Chrome.. I am also using Ubuntu 12.04. Do you by any chance know how to make it work in Chrome? Thank you :)

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and was able to reproduce it by enabling the Pepper Flash player. Diving in to the code a bit, it looks like it's failing in GIFPlayer when it calls urlLoader.load. Not sure what exactly it's failing on since there is no debug version of Pepper Flash.

Comment: I am facing the same issues. Did you find solution helgJ? I can't even play GIF in firefox. I am using the same code, Flex SDK 4.6, widnows7. But can't load GIF

Comment: When I track my code, I am getting security error SecurityError:Error #2148.. Its at player.load()